# Auto Procedure for SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Team I need a help

I sql server I have to daily extract the report from my table Grand_total
I have to get 3 column like this

```
**Only_On_27thnov_2017  1-22 novmber 2017     1_October_to _27_october2017
          500                  1000                9999**
```

In first column I want data as on yesterday,2 column I want data as on 1st day of current month till yesterday and
3 column i want data from 1st day of previous month till previous day of previous month(Example suppose today is 28th November so 01-October to 27 October 2017)

I doesn’t want to put date everyday and i want to make it schedule automatically

My orderdate is in Varchar(20)…I can change it in Date datatype also but I need in Varchar

How shloud I write the query for that
Note I have written query to split column into 3 part,I need again and again i don’t have to pass date.
Any way to write procedure so that it automatically run and i get the data

As data is coming from single table so i used Case if to split in 3 column

```
SELECT xy as COMPANY,Channel as Channel,regionname ,
**sum(CASE WHEN op.orderdate = ‘2017-11-27’ THEN inna ELSE ‘0’ END) AS SalesToday, **
**sum(CASE WHEN op.orderdate between ‘2017-11-01’ and ‘2017-11-27’ THEN inna ELSE ‘0’ END) AS till_1_to_yesterdaysales, **
**sum(CASE WHEN op.orderdate between ‘2017-10-01’ and ‘2017-10-27’ THEN inna ELSE ‘0’ END) AS till_1_to_yesterdaysales_previousmnth **
from GRAND_TOTAL OP

CHANNEL='10-GENERAL TRADE ’ group by xy, CHANNEL,regionname;
```

Answer (score 1):

add that to your query, it gives you the date that you wanted based on getdate()

```
cross apply
(
    select  [1st_day_of_prev_mth] = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0),
            [last_day_of_prev_mth]= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), -1),
            [1st_day_of_curr_mth] = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0),
            [yesterday]           = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
) d
```

then you can change your case statement to

```
 SUM(CASE WHEN op.orderdate = d.yesterday THEN inna ELSE 0 END) as SalesToday
```

[EDIT]

to make it a stored procedure

```
create procedure your_stored_procedure_name
as
begin
         -- Your query here
         select .....
         from   .....
end

To schedule it to execute automatically, refer to below link
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job

Comment: Appreciate..My question still left ..I want to make procedure so that it auto schedule and data goes into table from that table i will generate a report

Comment: once you have the query working, to make it a procedure, just use `create procedure`. And then schedule it at `SQL Agent`

Comment: I am new in that how should I arrange that cross apply query ..you said that i have to write sum query also.and u get [1st_day_of_prev_mth] as In third column I need data  bewteen previous month first day that is [1st_day_of_prev_mth] and previous month date day that is 28 october 2017...

Comment: Thankss..But I didn't get a column for october..U gave me 1st day for previous month ,Addition with that I also need previous month day example 2017-27-10 (27 october)

Comment: Ok i got that..SELECT DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate()-1));Thanks

Comment: added last_day_of_prev_mth

Comment: @Squirrel..Thank's Team